# NSTableView update selected cell after search

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, nstableview

I have NSTableView with some data. I want to get the name of the selected cell from NSTableView. That works when view is loaded and I simply click on it. 
[image: Table shows correct name of the clicked cell]
When I search through table and click on searched cell the selected item name doesn't update and it shows the value of the cell on that place before table was searched. 
[image]
Is
Can anyone point me to how to update the array when table is searched? Would appreciate any comments. Cheers.

Some code below showing how text2 variable for name of selected cell is derived:

```
var menuItems = [mainMenuData(calculationType: "Steel", calculationName: "Simply supported beam", calculationtoCode: "EN1993, BS5950"),
                mainMenuData(calculationType: "Concrete", calculationName: "Pad Foundations", calculationtoCode: "EN1992, BS8110"),
                mainMenuData(calculationType: "Loading", calculationName: "Wind loading", calculationtoCode: "EN1994, BS5675"),
                mainMenuData(calculationType: "Timber", calculationName: "timber rafter", calculationtoCode: "EN1995, BS3453"),
                mainMenuData(calculationType: "Steel", calculationName: "Portal Frame analysis", calculationtoCode: "EN1993, BS5950"),
                mainMenuData(calculationType: "Foundations", calculationName: "Pad foundations", calculationtoCode: "EN1992, BS8110")]

@IBOutlet var menuController: NSArrayController!
@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mainMenuTableView: NSTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedCalc: NSTextField!      

func updateMainMenu(){
    let text : String
    let text2 : String
    let itemSelected = mainMenuTableView.selectedRowIndexes.count
    let selected = mainMenuTableView.selectedRow

    if (itemSelected == 0) {
        text = "\(menuItems.count) items"
        text2 = "nothing selected"
    }
    else
    {
        text = "\(itemSelected) of \(menuItems.count) selected"
        text2 = "selected \(menuItems[selected].calculationName)"
    }

    statusLabel.stringValue = text
    selectedCalc.stringValue = text2
}

func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    updateMainMenu()

        }

@IBAction func searchChange(sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchString = sender.stringValue
    var predicate: NSPredicate? = nil
    if (searchString != ""){
        var dict: [String : AnyObject] = ["value" : searchString]
        predicate = searchPredicate.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(dict)


    }
    menuController.filterPredicate = predicate

}
```

Comment: Maybe try `tableView.continuous = YES`

Comment: @ProBlaster thanks. But where do I implement this? In tableview initialisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrangedObjects of menuController contains the filtered objects. selectedObjects of menuController contains the selected objects, if you did bind Selection Indexes.

Comment: thanks that prints objects in format 0x00 but how do I get value for selected row and middle column from arrangedObjects? I couldn't find method to achieve this.

Comment: Instead of `menuItems[selected].calculationName` do `menuController.arrangedObjects[selected].calculationName`.

Comment: Yes I tried that before but gives error 'Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'calculationName'. Any reason why? I set bindings for each column to menuController. Thanks for help.

Comment: Great solved it. menuController.arrangedObjects[selected].valueForKey("calculationName")! Gets the updated value.